# Mono Compiler crashed when compiling the file size of about 1.8MB

Tags: c#, .net, mono, monodevelop

I was trying to compile my source code using Mono compiler (mcs) and generate the dll file but the compilation hung and failed after some time.

## Command syntax used:

```
   mcs -unsafe -warn:0 ./<SourceCode> -out:test.dll -target:library
```

## OBSERVATION:

- CPU occupied 100% during execution
- This hanging is observed when the file size is 1.8MB (For about 1.2MB it passed)
- Error logs convey that memory of the heap should be increased how can it be increased in MONO?
- i am using the Mono: 4.6.1 from the path: http://download.mono-project.com/sources/mono/

## Failure log on console:

```
Too many heap sections: Increase MAXHINCR or MAX_HEAP_SECTS
Stacktrace:

  at <unknown> <0xffffffff>
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) object.__icall_wrapper_ves_icall_array_new_specific (intptr,int) <0x00057>
  at Mono.CSharp.VariableInfo.Initialize () <0x00038>
  at Mono.CSharp.VariableInfo..ctor (Mono.CSharp.VariableInfo,Mono.CSharp.TypeInfo) <0x0004e>
  at Mono.CSharp.VariableInfo.Initialize () <0x000a9>
  at Mono.CSharp.VariableInfo..ctor (Mono.CSharp.VariableInfo,Mono.CSharp.TypeInfo) <0x0004e>
  at Mono.CSharp.VariableInfo.Initialize () <0x000a9>
  at Mono.CSharp.VariableInfo..ctor (Mono.CSharp.VariableInfo,Mono.CSharp.TypeInfo) <0x0004e>
  at Mono.CSharp.VariableInfo.Initialize () <0x000a9>
  at Mono.CSharp.VariableInfo..ctor (Mono.CSharp.VariableInfo,Mono.CSharp.TypeInfo) <0x0004e>
  at Mono.CSharp.VariableInfo.Initialize () <0x000a9>
  at Mono.CSharp.VariableInfo..ctor (Mono.CSharp.VariableInfo,Mono.CSharp.TypeInfo) <0x0004e>
  at Mono.CSharp.VariableInfo.Initialize () <0x000a9>
  at Mono.CSharp.VariableInfo..ctor (Mono.CSharp.VariableInfo,Mono.CSharp.TypeInfo) <0x0004e>
  at Mono.CSharp.VariableInfo.Initialize () <0x000a9>
  at Mono.CSharp.VariableInfo..ctor (Mono.CSharp.VariableInfo,Mono.CSharp.TypeInfo) <0x0004e>
  at Mono.CSharp.VariableInfo.Initialize () <0x000a9>
  at Mono.CSharp.VariableInfo..ctor (Mono.CSharp.VariableInfo,Mono.CSharp.TypeInfo) <0x0004e>
  at Mono.CSharp.VariableInfo.Initialize () <0x000a9>
  at Mono.CSharp.VariableInfo..ctor (Mono.CSharp.VariableInfo,Mono.CSharp.TypeInfo) <0x0004e>
  at Mono.CSharp.VariableInfo.Initialize () <0x000a9>
  at Mono.CSharp.VariableInfo..ctor (Mono.CSharp.VariableInfo,Mono.CSharp.TypeInfo) <0x0004e>
  at Mono.CSharp.VariableInfo.Initialize () <0x000a9>
  at Mono.CSharp.VariableInfo..ctor (Mono.CSharp.VariableInfo,Mono.CSharp.TypeInfo) <0x0004e>
  at Mono.CSharp.VariableInfo.Initialize () <0x000a9>
  at Mono.CSharp.VariableInfo..ctor (Mono.CSharp.VariableInfo,Mono.CSharp.TypeInfo) <0x0004e>
  at Mono.CSharp.VariableInfo.Initialize () <0x000a9>
  at Mono.CSharp.VariableInfo..ctor (Mono.CSharp.VariableInfo,Mono.CSharp.TypeInfo) <0x0004e>
  at Mono.CSharp.VariableInfo.Initialize () <0x000a9>
  at Mono.CSharp.VariableInfo..ctor (Mono.CSharp.VariableInfo,Mono.CSharp.TypeInfo) <0x0004e>
  at Mono.CSharp.VariableInfo.Initialize () <0x000a9>
  at Mono.CSharp.VariableInfo..ctor (Mono.CSharp.VariableInfo,Mono.CSharp.TypeInfo) <0x0004e>
  at Mono.CSharp.VariableInfo.Initialize () <0x000a9>
  at Mono.CSharp.VariableInfo..ctor (Mono.CSharp.VariableInfo,Mono.CSharp.TypeInfo) <0x0004e>
  at Mono.CSharp.VariableInfo.Initialize () <0x000a9>
  at Mono.CSharp.VariableInfo..ctor (Mono.CSharp.VariableInfo,Mono.CSharp.TypeInfo) <0x0004e>
  at Mono.CSharp.VariableInfo.Initialize () <0x000a9>
  at Mono.CSharp.VariableInfo..ctor (Mono.CSharp.VariableInfo,Mono.CSharp.TypeInfo) <0x0004e>
  at Mono.CSharp.VariableInfo.Initialize () <0x000a9>
  at Mono.CSharp.VariableInfo..ctor (Mono.CSharp.VariableInfo,Mono.CSharp.TypeInfo) <0x0004e>
  at Mono.CSharp.VariableInfo.Initialize () <0x000a9>
  at Mono.CSharp.VariableInfo..ctor (Mono.CSharp.VariableInfo,Mono.CSharp.TypeInfo) <0x0004e>
  at Mono.CSharp.VariableInfo.Initialize () <0x000a9>
  at Mono.CSharp.VariableInfo..ctor (string,Mono.CSharp.TypeSpec,int,Mono.CSharp.IMemberContext) <0x0004f>
  at Mono.CSharp.VariableInfo.Create (Mono.CSharp.BlockContext,Mono.CSharp.LocalVariable) <0x00060>
  at Mono.CSharp.LocalVariable.PrepareAssignmentAnalysis (Mono.CSharp.BlockContext) <0x0002a>
  at Mono.CSharp.ToplevelBlock.AddThisVariable (Mono.CSharp.BlockContext) <0x000a8>
  at Mono.CSharp.Constructor.Emit () <0x0023d>
  at Mono.CSharp.TypeDefinition.Emit () <0x0048c>
  at Mono.CSharp.ClassOrStruct.Emit () <0x0007a>
  at Mono.CSharp.Struct.Emit () <0x00015>
  at Mono.CSharp.TypeDefinition.EmitContainer () <0x00025>
  at Mono.CSharp.TypeContainer.EmitContainer () <0x00045>
  at Mono.CSharp.NamespaceContainer.EmitContainer () <0x0001c>
  at Mono.CSharp.TypeContainer.EmitContainer () <0x00045>
  at Mono.CSharp.NamespaceContainer.EmitContainer () <0x0001c>
  at Mono.CSharp.TypeContainer.EmitContainer () <0x00045>
  at Mono.CSharp.ModuleContainer.EmitContainer () <0x00178>
  at Mono.CSharp.AssemblyDefinition.Emit () <0x00137>
  at Mono.CSharp.AssemblyDefinitionStatic.Emit () <0x00227>
  at Mono.CSharp.Driver.Compile () <0x00642>
  at Mono.CSharp.Driver.Main (string[]) <0x0012f>
  at (wrapper runtime-invoke) <Module>.runtime_invoke_int_object (object,intptr,intptr,intptr) <0x000c5>

Native stacktrace:

        /mnt/VOLUME/UE_Mobility_POC/MYFOLDER/src/mono-4_6_1/mono-install/bin/mono() [0x4b6b08]
        /lib64/libpthread.so.0(+0x11f70) [0x7f4596d41f70]
        /lib64/libc.so.6(gsignal+0x10b) [0x7f4596793edb]
        /lib64/libc.so.6(abort+0x151) [0x7f4596795291]
        /mnt/VOLUME/UE_Mobility_POC/MYFOLDER/src/mono-4_6_1/mono-install/bin/mono(GC_enable+0) [0x62cf49]
        /mnt/VOLUME/UE_Mobility_POC/MYFOLDER/src/mono-4_6_1/mono-install/bin/mono(GC_add_to_heap+0x29) [0x622e16]
        /mnt/VOLUME/UE_Mobility_POC/MYFOLDER/src/mono-4_6_1/mono-install/bin/mono(GC_expand_hp_inner+0x1e8) [0x623294]
        /mnt/VOLUME/UE_Mobility_POC/MYFOLDER/src/mono-4_6_1/mono-install/bin/mono(GC_collect_or_expand+0x145) [0x623485]
        /mnt/VOLUME/UE_Mobility_POC/MYFOLDER/src/mono-4_6_1/mono-install/bin/mono(GC_allocobj+0x109) [0x623645]
        /mnt/VOLUME/UE_Mobility_POC/MYFOLDER/src/mono-4_6_1/mono-install/bin/mono(GC_generic_malloc_inner+0xea) [0x62724e]
        /mnt/VOLUME/UE_Mobility_POC/MYFOLDER/src/mono-4_6_1/mono-install/bin/mono(GC_generic_malloc_many+0x440) [0x628391]
        /mnt/VOLUME/UE_Mobility_POC/MYFOLDER/src/mono-4_6_1/mono-install/bin/mono(GC_local_malloc+0x12e) [0x6318c2]
        /mnt/VOLUME/UE_Mobility_POC/MYFOLDER/src/mono-4_6_1/mono-install/bin/mono() [0x5ea0e0]
        /mnt/VOLUME/UE_Mobility_POC/MYFOLDER/src/mono-4_6_1/mono-install/bin/mono() [0x5c8057]
        /mnt/VOLUME/UE_Mobility_POC/MYFOLDER/src/mono-4_6_1/mono-install/bin/mono() [0x5c81ed]
        [0x41020578]

Debug info from gdb:

[New LWP 7247]
[New LWP 7248]
[New LWP 7249]
[New LWP 7250]
[New LWP 7251]
[New LWP 7252]
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib64/libthread_db.so.1".
0x00007f4596d418da in waitpid () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
  Id   Target Id         Frame
* 1    Thread 0x7f45978ff780 (LWP 7246) "Main" 0x00007f4596d418da in waitpid () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
  2    Thread 0x7f459675e700 (LWP 7247) "Main" 0x00007f4596d3d50c in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
  3    Thread 0x7f4595f5d700 (LWP 7248) "Main" 0x00007f4596d3d50c in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
  4    Thread 0x7f459575c700 (LWP 7249) "Main" 0x00007f4596d3d50c in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
  5    Thread 0x7f4594f5b700 (LWP 7250) "Main" 0x00007f4596d3d50c in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
  6    Thread 0x7f459475a700 (LWP 7251) "Main" 0x00007f4596d3d50c in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
  7    Thread 0x7f459302a700 (LWP 7252) "Finalizer" 0x00007f4596d3fd96 in do_futex_wait.constprop () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0

Thread 7 (Thread 0x7f459302a700 (LWP 7252)):
#0  0x00007f4596d3fd96 in do_futex_wait.constprop () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x00007f4596d3fe88 in __new_sem_wait_slow.constprop.0 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#2  0x00000000005bf53c in mono_os_sem_wait (flags=MONO_SEM_FLAGS_ALERTABLE, sem=0x960880 <finalizer_sem>) at ../../mono/utils/mono-os-semaphore.h:166
#3  mono_coop_sem_wait (sem=0x960880 <finalizer_sem>, flags=MONO_SEM_FLAGS_ALERTABLE) at ../../mono/utils/mono-coop-semaphore.h:40
#4  finalizer_thread (unused=unused@entry=0x0) at gc.c:761
#5  0x00000000005a01f9 in start_wrapper_internal (data=<optimized out>) at threads.c:740
#6  start_wrapper (data=<optimized out>) at threads.c:788
#7  0x000000000061ec4a in inner_start_thread (arg=<optimized out>) at mono-threads-posix.c:92
#8  0x0000000000632cf5 in GC_start_routine (arg=0x7f4597823fc0) at pthread_support.c:1508
#9  0x00007f4596d375da in start_thread () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#10 0x00007f4596855cef in clone () from /lib64/libc.so.6

Thread 6 (Thread 0x7f459475a700 (LWP 7251)):
#0  0x00007f4596d3d50c in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x0000000000633079 in GC_wait_marker () at pthread_support.c:1903
#2  0x000000000062a309 in GC_help_marker (my_mark_no=29) at mark.c:1116
#3  0x0000000000631d1f in GC_mark_thread (id=0x4) at pthread_support.c:555
#4  0x00007f4596d375da in start_thread () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#5  0x00007f4596855cef in clone () from /lib64/libc.so.6

Thread 5 (Thread 0x7f4594f5b700 (LWP 7250)):
#0  0x00007f4596d3d50c in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x0000000000633079 in GC_wait_marker () at pthread_support.c:1903
#2  0x000000000062a309 in GC_help_marker (my_mark_no=29) at mark.c:1116
#3  0x0000000000631d1f in GC_mark_thread (id=0x3) at pthread_support.c:555
#4  0x00007f4596d375da in start_thread () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#5  0x00007f4596855cef in clone () from /lib64/libc.so.6

Thread 4 (Thread 0x7f459575c700 (LWP 7249)):
#0  0x00007f4596d3d50c in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x0000000000633079 in GC_wait_marker () at pthread_support.c:1903
#2  0x000000000062a309 in GC_help_marker (my_mark_no=29) at mark.c:1116
#3  0x0000000000631d1f in GC_mark_thread (id=0x2) at pthread_support.c:555
#4  0x00007f4596d375da in start_thread () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#5  0x00007f4596855cef in clone () from /lib64/libc.so.6

Thread 3 (Thread 0x7f4595f5d700 (LWP 7248)):
#0  0x00007f4596d3d50c in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x0000000000633079 in GC_wait_marker () at pthread_support.c:1903
#2  0x000000000062a309 in GC_help_marker (my_mark_no=29) at mark.c:1116
#3  0x0000000000631d1f in GC_mark_thread (id=0x1) at pthread_support.c:555
#4  0x00007f4596d375da in start_thread () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#5  0x00007f4596855cef in clone () from /lib64/libc.so.6

Thread 2 (Thread 0x7f459675e700 (LWP 7247)):
#0  0x00007f4596d3d50c in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x0000000000633079 in GC_wait_marker () at pthread_support.c:1903
#2  0x000000000062a309 in GC_help_marker (my_mark_no=29) at mark.c:1116
#3  0x0000000000631d1f in GC_mark_thread (id=0x0) at pthread_support.c:555
#4  0x00007f4596d375da in start_thread () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#5  0x00007f4596855cef in clone () from /lib64/libc.so.6

Thread 1 (Thread 0x7f45978ff780 (LWP 7246)):
#0  0x00007f4596d418da in waitpid () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x00000000004b6bce in mono_handle_native_sigsegv (signal=<optimized out>, ctx=<optimized out>, info=<optimized out>) at mini-exceptions.c:2427
#2  <signal handler called>
#3  0x00007f4596793edb in raise () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#4  0x00007f4596795291 in abort () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#5  0x000000000062cf49 in GC_abort (msg=0x6f48f8 "Too many heap sections: Increase MAXHINCR or MAX_HEAP_SECTS") at misc.c:1122
#6  0x0000000000622e16 in GC_add_to_heap (p=0x7f448e2c5000, bytes=8388608) at alloc.c:848
#7  0x0000000000623294 in GC_expand_hp_inner (n=2048) at alloc.c:1002
#8  0x0000000000623485 in GC_collect_or_expand (needed_blocks=1, ignore_off_page=0) at alloc.c:1078
#9  0x0000000000623645 in GC_allocobj (sz=6, kind=1) at alloc.c:1133
#10 0x000000000062724e in GC_generic_malloc_inner (lb=48, k=1) at malloc.c:136
#11 0x0000000000628391 in GC_generic_malloc_many (lb=48, k=1, result=0x962718 <first_thread+664>) at mallocx.c:513
#12 0x00000000006318c2 in GC_local_malloc (bytes=48) at pthread_support.c:373
#13 0x00000000005ea0e0 in mono_gc_alloc_vector (vtable=vtable@entry=0x1e64f30, size=48, max_length=max_length@entry=2) at boehm-gc.c:689
#14 0x00000000005c8057 in mono_array_new_specific_checked (vtable=0x1e64f30, n=2, error=0x7ffc59c703a0) at object.c:5916
#15 0x00000000005c81ed in ves_icall_array_new_specific (vtable=<optimized out>, n=<optimized out>) at object.c:5930
#16 0x0000000041020578 in ?? ()
#17 0x00007f458a698508 in ?? ()
#18 0x00007f45977a5d68 in ?? ()
#19 0x00007f448f3031c0 in ?? ()
#20 0x00007f458a1b69f0 in ?? ()
#21 0x00007f448f3031c0 in ?? ()
#22 0x00000000018c6210 in ?? ()
#23 0x0000000001aff158 in ?? ()
#24 0x00007ffc59c70db0 in ?? ()
#25 0x00007ffc59c70420 in ?? ()
#26 0x00007f45925a0d59 in Mono_CSharp_VariableInfo_Initialize (this=...) at /mnt/rsm_checkout/BASEFOLDER/MYFOLDER/src/mono-4_6_1/mono-4.6.1/mcs/mcs/flowanalysis.cs:344
#27 0x00007f45925a0d0f in Mono_CSharp_VariableInfo__ctor_Mono_CSharp_VariableInfo_Mono_CSharp_TypeInfo (this=..., parent=..., type=...) at /mnt/rsm_checkout/BASEFOLDER/MYFOLDER/src/mono-4_6_1/mono-4.6.1/mcs/mcs/flowanalysis.cs:337
#28 0x00007f45925a0dca in Mono_CSharp_VariableInfo_Initialize (this=...) at /mnt/rsm_checkout/BASEFOLDER/MYFOLDER/src/mono-4_6_1/mono-4.6.1/mcs/mcs/flowanalysis.cs:347
#29 0x00007f45925a0d0f in Mono_CSharp_VariableInfo__ctor_Mono_CSharp_VariableInfo_Mono_CSharp_TypeInfo (this=..., parent=..., type=...) at /mnt/rsm_checkout/BASEFOLDER/MYFOLDER/src/mono-4_6_1/mono-4.6.1/mcs/mcs/flowanalysis.cs:337
#30 0x00007f45925a0dca in Mono_CSharp_VariableInfo_Initialize (this=...) at /mnt/rsm_checkout/BASEFOLDER/MYFOLDER/src/mono-4_6_1/mono-4.6.1/mcs/mcs/flowanalysis.cs:347
#31 0x00007f45925a0d0f in Mono_CSharp_VariableInfo__ctor_Mono_CSharp_VariableInfo_Mono_CSharp_TypeInfo (this=..., parent=..., type=...) at /mnt/rsm_checkout/BASEFOLDER/MYFOLDER/src/mono-4_6_1/mono-4.6.1/mcs/mcs/flowanalysis.cs:337
#32 0x00007f45925a0dca in Mono_CSharp_VariableInfo_Initialize (this=...) at /mnt/rsm_checkout/BASEFOLDER/MYFOLDER/src/mono-4_6_1/mono-4.6.1/mcs/mcs/flowanalysis.cs:347
#33 0x00007f45925a0d0f in Mono_CSharp_VariableInfo__ctor_Mono_CSharp_VariableInfo_Mono_CSharp_TypeInfo (this=..., parent=..., type=...) at /mnt/rsm_checkout/BASEFOLDER/MYFOLDER/src/mono-4_6_1/mono-4.6.1/mcs/mcs/flowanalysis.cs:337
#34 0x00007f45925a0dca in Mono_CSharp_VariableInfo_Initialize (this=...) at /mnt/rsm_checkout/BASEFOLDER/MYFOLDER/src/mono-4_6_1/mono-4.6.1/mcs/mcs/flowanalysis.cs:347
#35 0x00007f45925a0d0f in Mono_CSharp_VariableInfo__ctor_Mono_CSharp_VariableInfo_Mono_CSharp_TypeInfo (this=..., parent=..., type=...) at /mnt/rsm_checkout/BASEFOLDER/MYFOLDER/src/mono-4_6_1/mono-4.6.1/mcs/mcs/flowanalysis.cs:337
#36 0x00007f45925a0dca in Mono_CSharp_VariableInfo_Initialize (this=...) at /mnt/rsm_checkout/BASEFOLDER/MYFOLDER/src/mono-4_6_1/mono-4.6.1/mcs/mcs/flowanalysis.cs:347
#37 0x00007f45925a0d0f in Mono_CSharp_VariableInfo__ctor_Mono_CSharp_VariableInfo_Mono_CSharp_TypeInfo (this=..., parent=..., type=...) at /mnt/rsm_checkout/BASEFOLDER/MYFOLDER/src/mono-4_6_1/mono-4.6.1/mcs/mcs/flowanalysis.cs:337
#38 0x00007f45925a0dca in Mono_CSharp_VariableInfo_Initialize (this=...) at /mnt/rsm_checkout/BASEFOLDER/MYFOLDER/src/mono-4_6_1/mono-4.6.1/mcs/mcs/flowanalysis.cs:347
#39 0x00007f45925a0d0f in Mono_CSharp_VariableInfo__ctor_Mono_CSharp_VariableInfo_Mono_CSharp_TypeInfo (this=..., parent=..., type=...) at /mnt/rsm_checkout/BASEFOLDER/MYFOLDER/src/mono-4_6_1/mono-4.6.1/mcs/mcs/flowanalysis.cs:337
#40 0x00007f45925a0dca in Mono_CSharp_VariableInfo_Initialize (this=...) at /mnt/rsm_checkout/BASEFOLDER/MYFOLDER/src/mono-4_6_1/mono-4.6.1/mcs/mcs/flowanalysis.cs:347
#41 0x00007f45925a0d0f in Mono_CSharp_VariableInfo__ctor_Mono_CSharp_VariableInfo_Mono_CSharp_TypeInfo (this=..., parent=..., type=...) at /mnt/rsm_checkout/BASEFOLDER/MYFOLDER/src/mono-4_6_1/mono-4.6.1/mcs/mcs/flowanalysis.cs:337
#42 0x00007f45925a0dca in Mono_CSharp_VariableInfo_Initialize (this=...) at /mnt/rsm_checkout/BASEFOLDER/MYFOLDER/src/mono-4_6_1/mono-4.6.1/mcs/mcs/flowanalysis.cs:347
#43 0x00007f45925a0d0f in Mono_CSharp_VariableInfo__ctor_Mono_CSharp_VariableInfo_Mono_CSharp_TypeInfo (this=..., parent=..., type=...) at /mnt/rsm_checkout/BASEFOLDER/MYFOLDER/src/mono-4_6_1/mono-4.6.1/mcs/mcs/flowanalysis.cs:337
#44 0x00007f45925a0dca in Mono_CSharp_VariableInfo_Initialize (this=...) at /mnt/rsm_checkout/BASEFOLDER/MYFOLDER/src/mono-4_6_1/mono-4.6.1/mcs/mcs/flowanalysis.cs:347
#45 0x00007f45925a0d0f in Mono_CSharp_VariableInfo__ctor_Mono_CSharp_VariableInfo_Mono_CSharp_TypeInfo (this=..., parent=..., type=...) at /mnt/rsm_checkout/BASEFOLDER/MYFOLDER/src/mono-4_6_1/mono-4.6.1/mcs/mcs/flowanalysis.cs:337
#46 0x00007f45925a0dca in Mono_CSharp_VariableInfo_Initialize (this=...) at /mnt/rsm_checkout/BASEFOLDER/MYFOLDER/src/mono-4_6_1/mono-4.6.1/mcs/mcs/flowanalysis.cs:347
#47 0x00007f45925a0d0f in Mono_CSharp_VariableInfo__ctor_Mono_CSharp_VariableInfo_Mono_CSharp_TypeInfo (this=..., parent=..., type=...) at /mnt/rsm_checkout/BASEFOLDER/MYFOLDER/src/mono-4_6_1/mono-4.6.1/mcs/mcs/flowanalysis.cs:337
#48 0x00007f45925a0dca in Mono_CSharp_VariableInfo_Initialize (this=...) at /mnt/rsm_checkout/BASEFOLDER/MYFOLDER/src/mono-4_6_1/mono-4.6.1/mcs/mcs/flowanalysis.cs:347
#49 0x00007f45925a0d0f in Mono_CSharp_VariableInfo__ctor_Mono_CSharp_VariableInfo_Mono_CSharp_TypeInfo (this=..., parent=..., type=...) at /mnt/rsm_checkout/BASEFOLDER/MYFOLDER/src/mono-4_6_1/mono-4.6.1/mcs/mcs/flowanalysis.cs:337
#50 0x00007f45925a0dca in Mono_CSharp_VariableInfo_Initialize (this=...) at /mnt/rsm_checkout/BASEFOLDER/MYFOLDER/src/mono-4_6_1/mono-4.6.1/mcs/mcs/flowanalysis.cs:347
#51 0x00007f45925a0d0f in Mono_CSharp_VariableInfo__ctor_Mono_CSharp_VariableInfo_Mono_CSharp_TypeInfo (this=..., parent=..., type=...) at /mnt/rsm_checkout/BASEFOLDER/MYFOLDER/src/mono-4_6_1/mono-4.6.1/mcs/mcs/flowanalysis.cs:337
#52 0x00007f45925a0dca in Mono_CSharp_VariableInfo_Initialize (this=...) at /mnt/rsm_checkout/BASEFOLDER/MYFOLDER/src/mono-4_6_1/mono-4.6.1/mcs/mcs/flowanalysis.cs:347
#53 0x00007f45925a0d0f in Mono_CSharp_VariableInfo__ctor_Mono_CSharp_VariableInfo_Mono_CSharp_TypeInfo (this=..., parent=..., type=...) at /mnt/rsm_checkout/BASEFOLDER/MYFOLDER/src/mono-4_6_1/mono-4.6.1/mcs/mcs/flowanalysis.cs:337
#54 0x00007f45925a0dca in Mono_CSharp_VariableInfo_Initialize (this=...) at /mnt/rsm_checkout/BASEFOLDER/MYFOLDER/src/mono-4_6_1/mono-4.6.1/mcs/mcs/flowanalysis.cs:347
#55 0x00007f45925a0d0f in Mono_CSharp_VariableInfo__ctor_Mono_CSharp_VariableInfo_Mono_CSharp_TypeInfo (this=..., parent=..., type=...) at /mnt/rsm_checkout/BASEFOLDER/MYFOLDER/src/mono-4_6_1/mono-4.6.1/mcs/mcs/flowanalysis.cs:337
#56 0x00007f45925a0dca in Mono_CSharp_VariableInfo_Initialize (this=...) at /mnt/rsm_checkout/BASEFOLDER/MYFOLDER/src/mono-4_6_1/mono-4.6.1/mcs/mcs/flowanalysis.cs:347
#57 0x00007f45925a0d0f in Mono_CSharp_VariableInfo__ctor_Mono_CSharp_VariableInfo_Mono_CSharp_TypeInfo (this=..., parent=..., type=...) at /mnt/rsm_checkout/BASEFOLDER/MYFOLDER/src/mono-4_6_1/mono-4.6.1/mcs/mcs/flowanalysis.cs:337
#58 0x00007f45925a0dca in Mono_CSharp_VariableInfo_Initialize (this=...) at /mnt/rsm_checkout/BASEFOLDER/MYFOLDER/src/mono-4_6_1/mono-4.6.1/mcs/mcs/flowanalysis.cs:347
#59 0x00007f45925a0d0f in Mono_CSharp_VariableInfo__ctor_Mono_CSharp_VariableInfo_Mono_CSharp_TypeInfo (this=..., parent=..., type=...) at /mnt/rsm_checkout/BASEFOLDER/MYFOLDER/src/mono-4_6_1/mono-4.6.1/mcs/mcs/flowanalysis.cs:337
#60 0x00007f45925a0dca in Mono_CSharp_VariableInfo_Initialize (this=...) at /mnt/rsm_checkout/BASEFOLDER/MYFOLDER/src/mono-4_6_1/mono-4.6.1/mcs/mcs/flowanalysis.cs:347
#61 0x00007f45925a0d0f in Mono_CSharp_VariableInfo__ctor_Mono_CSharp_VariableInfo_Mono_CSharp_TypeInfo (this=..., parent=..., type=...) at /mnt/rsm_checkout/BASEFOLDER/MYFOLDER/src/mono-4_6_1/mono-4.6.1/mcs/mcs/flowanalysis.cs:337
#62 0x00007f45925a0dca in Mono_CSharp_VariableInfo_Initialize (this=...) at /mnt/rsm_checkout/BASEFOLDER/MYFOLDER/src/mono-4_6_1/mono-4.6.1/mcs/mcs/flowanalysis.cs:347
#63 0x00007f45925a0d0f in Mono_CSharp_VariableInfo__ctor_Mono_CSharp_VariableInfo_Mono_CSharp_TypeInfo (this=..., parent=..., type=...) at /mnt/rsm_checkout/BASEFOLDER/MYFOLDER/src/mono-4_6_1/mono-4.6.1/mcs/mcs/flowanalysis.cs:337
#64 0x00007f45925a0dca in Mono_CSharp_VariableInfo_Initialize (this=...) at /mnt/rsm_checkout/BASEFOLDER/MYFOLDER/src/mono-4_6_1/mono-4.6.1/mcs/mcs/flowanalysis.cs:347
#65 0x00007f45925a0d0f in Mono_CSharp_VariableInfo__ctor_Mono_CSharp_VariableInfo_Mono_CSharp_TypeInfo (this=..., parent=..., type=...) at /mnt/rsm_checkout/BASEFOLDER/MYFOLDER/src/mono-4_6_1/mono-4.6.1/mcs/mcs/flowanalysis.cs:337
#66 0x00007f45925a0dca in Mono_CSharp_VariableInfo_Initialize (this=...) at /mnt/rsm_checkout/BASEFOLDER/MYFOLDER/src/mono-4_6_1/mono-4.6.1/mcs/mcs/flowanalysis.cs:347
#67 0x00007f45925a0cb0 in Mono_CSharp_VariableInfo__ctor_string_Mono_CSharp_TypeSpec_int_Mono_CSharp_IMemberContext (this=..., name=0x7f459779f140, type=..., offset=0, context=...) at /mnt/rsm_checkout/BASEFOLDER/MYFOLDER/src/mono-4_6_1/mono-4.6.1/mcs/mcs/flowanalysis.cs:325
#68 0x00007f45925a0eb1 in Mono_CSharp_VariableInfo_Create_Mono_CSharp_BlockContext_Mono_CSharp_LocalVariable (bc=..., variable=...) at /mnt/rsm_checkout/BASEFOLDER/MYFOLDER/src/mono-4_6_1/mono-4.6.1/mcs/mcs/flowanalysis.cs:355
#69 0x00007f4592608cfb in Mono_CSharp_LocalVariable_PrepareAssignmentAnalysis_Mono_CSharp_BlockContext (this=..., bc=...) at /mnt/rsm_checkout/BASEFOLDER/MYFOLDER/src/mono-4_6_1/mono-4.6.1/mcs/mcs/statement.cs:2607
#70 0x00007f459260ea19 in Mono_CSharp_ToplevelBlock_AddThisVariable_Mono_CSharp_BlockContext (this=..., bc=...) at /mnt/rsm_checkout/BASEFOLDER/MYFOLDER/src/mono-4_6_1/mono-4.6.1/mcs/mcs/statement.cs:4403
#71 0x00007f45925d595e in Mono_CSharp_Constructor_Emit (this=...) at /mnt/rsm_checkout/BASEFOLDER/MYFOLDER/src/mono-4_6_1/mono-4.6.1/mcs/mcs/method.cs:1763
#72 0x00007f4592519d8d in Mono_CSharp_TypeDefinition_Emit (this=...) at /mnt/rsm_checkout/BASEFOLDER/MYFOLDER/src/mono-4_6_1/mono-4.6.1/mcs/mcs/class.cs:2212
#73 0x00007f459251bfdb in Mono_CSharp_ClassOrStruct_Emit (this=...) at /mnt/rsm_checkout/BASEFOLDER/MYFOLDER/src/mono-4_6_1/mono-4.6.1/mcs/mcs/class.cs:2728
#74 0x00007f459251dd36 in Mono_CSharp_Struct_Emit (this=...) at /mnt/rsm_checkout/BASEFOLDER/MYFOLDER/src/mono-4_6_1/mono-4.6.1/mcs/mcs/class.cs:3096
#75 0x00007f4592519ff6 in Mono_CSharp_TypeDefinition_EmitContainer (this=...) at /mnt/rsm_checkout/BASEFOLDER/MYFOLDER/src/mono-4_6_1/mono-4.6.1/mcs/mcs/class.cs:2245
#76 0x00007f4592512e16 in Mono_CSharp_TypeContainer_EmitContainer (this=...) at /mnt/rsm_checkout/BASEFOLDER/MYFOLDER/src/mono-4_6_1/mono-4.6.1/mcs/mcs/class.cs:335
#77 0x00007f45925de7ed in Mono_CSharp_NamespaceContainer_EmitContainer (this=...) at /mnt/rsm_checkout/BASEFOLDER/MYFOLDER/src/mono-4_6_1/mono-4.6.1/mcs/mcs/namespace.cs:876
#78 0x00007f4592512e16 in Mono_CSharp_TypeContainer_EmitContainer (this=...) at /mnt/rsm_checkout/BASEFOLDER/MYFOLDER/src/mono-4_6_1/mono-4.6.1/mcs/mcs/class.cs:335
#79 0x00007f45925de7ed in Mono_CSharp_NamespaceContainer_EmitContainer (this=...) at /mnt/rsm_checkout/BASEFOLDER/MYFOLDER/src/mono-4_6_1/mono-4.6.1/mcs/mcs/namespace.cs:876
#80 0x00007f4592512e16 in Mono_CSharp_TypeContainer_EmitContainer (this=...) at /mnt/rsm_checkout/BASEFOLDER/MYFOLDER/src/mono-4_6_1/mono-4.6.1/mcs/mcs/class.cs:335
#81 0x00007f45925ff3c9 in Mono_CSharp_ModuleContainer_EmitContainer (this=...) at /mnt/rsm_checkout/BASEFOLDER/MYFOLDER/src/mono-4_6_1/mono-4.6.1/mcs/mcs/module.cs:602
#82 0x00007f45924eaf98 in Mono_CSharp_AssemblyDefinition_Emit (this=...) at /mnt/rsm_checkout/BASEFOLDER/MYFOLDER/src/mono-4_6_1/mono-4.6.1/mcs/mcs/assembly.cs:529
#83 0x00007f45925bf2f8 in Mono_CSharp_AssemblyDefinitionStatic_Emit (this=...) at /mnt/rsm_checkout/BASEFOLDER/MYFOLDER/src/mono-4_6_1/mono-4.6.1/mcs/mcs/ikvm.cs:215
#84 0x00007f45925495d3 in Mono_CSharp_Driver_Compile (this=...) at /mnt/rsm_checkout/BASEFOLDER/MYFOLDER/src/mono-4_6_1/mono-4.6.1/mcs/mcs/driver.cs:391
#85 0x00007f4592548ba0 in Mono_CSharp_Driver_Main_string__ (args=0x7f45977a6fd8) at /mnt/rsm_checkout/BASEFOLDER/MYFOLDER/src/mono-4_6_1/mono-4.6.1/mcs/mcs/driver.cs:187
#86 0x00000000410200a6 in ?? ()
#87 0x000000000000001f in ?? ()
#88 0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()

=================================================================
Got a SIGABRT while executing native code. This usually indicates
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries
used by your application.
=================================================================

Aborted (core dumped)
```